# How can I write a SQL update query with a where clause using Entity Framework .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I only want to update a field based on the condition that is mentionned below. I know how to write it in SQL. I'm not sure how to accomplish this in entity framework.

```
UPDATE Table SET SomeDateTime = @NewDateTime WHERE Id = @MyId AND SomeDateTime > @NewDateTime
```

I want to use this particular query due to using a micro service architecture.

Comment: maybe you are looking for this extension: https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-update

Comment: Is `Id` a primary key?

Comment: @Kevin have you tried to use `ExecuteSqlCommand`? give a check my answer.

Comment: @AlexandreRodrigues I was hoping to avoid that ... However, that is looking like the best answer .. so far anyway.

Comment: @Kevin  I totally understand that.. in this type of situations I always think twice..the thing is if you were handling a object and then doing a update I would change a object and call SaveChanges, but that's not the case.. here is an update directly to the table, If that table has millions of rows you want perform sql to get performance on that. I'll add this explanation at my answer.

Comment: Though legal, that quite much throws away the reason to use Entity at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want use sql directly you can use `ExecuteSqlCommand`

If you were handling a object and then doing a update I would change a object and call `SaveChanges`, but that's not the case.. here is an update directly to the table, If that table has millions of rows you want perform `sql` to get performance on that.

example

```
using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var commandText = "UPDATE Table SET SomeDateTime = @NewDateTime WHERE Id = @MyId AND SomeDateTime > @NewDateTime";
    var newDateTime = new SqlParameter("@NewDateTime", myDateValue);
    var myId = new SqlParameter("@MyId", myIdValue);

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText,  new[]{newDateTime,myId});
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to add using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational;

Answer (score 6):

Starting from EF Core 7, you can use new method `ExecuteUpdate` / `ExecuteUpdateAsync`:

```cs
context.Table
   .Where(t => t.Id == myId && t.SomeDateTime > newDateTime)
   .ExecuteUpdate(b => b.SetProperty(x => x.SomeDateTime, x => newDateTime));
```

Comment: For multiple properties you can chain them `SetProperty(x => x.SomeDateTime, x => newDateTime).SetProperty(x => x.SomeInt, x => 123)`

Answer (score 2):

If `Id` is a primary key, which means you only find one record with it, then the way I'd update it is retrieving the record, changing the value of the properties I want to edit, then saving the changes on the context.

```
int MyId = ...
DateTime NewDateTime = ...

using (YourDbContext dbContext = new YourDbContext())
{
   YourObject obj = dbContext.YourObjects.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == MyId && item.SomeDateTime > NewDateTime)
   if (obj != null)
   {
      obj.SomeDateTime = NewDateTime;
      dbContext.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: This will only update individual records by their primary key value (possibly with optimistic concurrency too) instead of updating multiple records using arbitrary criteria.

Comment: OP mentioned an **Id** in their query, which I suppose is the primary key, so of course that updates only one record. I don't understand your point, sorry.

Comment: @StackLloyd Indeed. I only looked at the question's title and didn't read the body of his post :D I just made the incorrect assumption they were looking to update multiple records using Linq/EF.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this this way:

```
 try
            {
               var usersToUpdate = await dbContext.MyList.Where(x=>x.Id==myId).ToListAsync();

               usersToUpdate.ForEach(x=>{..make updates..});

                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
        {
           ..Error handling..
        }
```

P.S if you want to see how many records where updated you can assign a variable to saveChangesAsync:

```
var result= await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample code to find a specific record of the database and then update it with the help of EF Core:

```
public bool UpdateTable()
{
    DatabaseContext _db = new DatabaseContext(); //database context instance
    int MyId = 100; //sample Id
    DateTime MyDateTime = new DateTime(2019, 5, 24, 12, 30, 52); //sample DateTime
    var p = _db.Table.Where(x => x.Id == MyId && x.SomeDateTime > 
        MyDateTime ).FirstOrDefault(); //the targeted record of the database
    if (p != null)
    {
       p.SomeDateTime = DateTime.Now;
       _db.SaveChanges();
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```